# Encrypting Passwords In Linux For Later Use

Tags: linux, cron, password, encryption

This is an interesting read that I found regarding encrypting passwords for later use,
https://4sysops.com/archives/scheduling-powershell-scripts-with-usernames-and-encrypted-passwords/

Essentially, a user creates login credentials one time and Windows Scheduler can access this encrypted token when it performs jobs under that user account. The token can then be used to decrypt a file or string containing a credentials for an external service such as Twitter.

I am wondering if something like this is available in Linux?

Comment: I know you are looking for a tool or similar solution purpose built for Linux but [powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell) can be installed on Linux. Meaning it may be possible to do exactly what is pointed out in your link on a Linux system using powershell.